# Delete function of a binary search tree not working properly

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

This is a delete function of a binary search tree coded in C, but this is not working properly. The node which is supposed to be deleted is replaced by a garbage value.

```
void delete(struct node* root,int data)
{
{
    struct node* t1;
    if(root==0) {
        printf("element not found\n");
    } else if(data>root->data) {
        delete(root->right,data);
    } else if(data<root->data) {
        delete(root->left,data);
    } else {
        if(root->right&&root->left) {
            t1=findmin(root->right);
            root->data=t1->data;
            free(t1);
        } else {
            t1=root;
            if(root->right) {
                root=root->right;
            } else if(root->left) {
                root=root->left;
            }
            free(t1);
        }
    }
}
```

it is working per se, but the node  is not getting deleted and is replaced by some garbage value.

```
struct node* findmin(struct node* t) {
    if(t==NULL) {
        return NULL;
    } else if(t->left) {
        findmin(t->left);
    } else
        return t; 
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific than 'not working properly' and also improve the code formatting. It might also be worthwhile to read through the [asking howto](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `findmin(t->left);` should be `return findmin(t->left);`! The compiler most likely told you that (more or less indirectly).

Comment: i added return.it doesnt make a difference.and by "not working properly" i mean that the required is neither removed nor deleted. the only change that , it is replaced by 0 in  the first call and the next time it is replaced by junk values

Comment: The node above is still pointing to the deleted node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing root in the function parameters and then inside the following block of your code you are reassigning it.

```
            else
        {
                t1=root;
                if(root->right)
                {
                        root=root->right;
                }
                else if(root->left)
                {
                        root=root->left;
                }
                free(t1);
        }
```

This reassignment is temporary to current function call (because it's been passed by value).
alternatively you can do the same is by returning the new root of the tree after deletion of the specified node.

```
struct node* delete(struct node* root, int key)
{
    if (root == NULL) return root;

    if (key < root->key)
        root->left = delete(root->left, key);

    else if (key > root->key)
        root->right = delete(root->right, key);

    else
    {
        // node with only one child or no child
        if (root->left == NULL)
        {
            struct node *temp = root->right;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        else if (root->right == NULL)
        {
            struct node *temp = root->left;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }

        struct node* temp = findmin(root->right);

        root->key = temp->key;

        root->right = delete(root->right, temp->key);
    }
    return root;
}
```

Comment: i have declared the variable "root" globally.then how is it pass by value??
i implemented the changes and the program worked.

Comment: hey .. global variable hack wouldn't work because its a recursive function. Each instance of the function call would have different value assigned to root. If you wonna stick to void return, then you could probably pass parameters by reference in c++, although I am not sure.